# How to get the already created IoTHub's connection string using java code?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have created an IoTHub using rest api and now I want to add a device in the hub, that too using the rest api. However for that i need the created hub's connection string, which i must get using the java code or rest api, not by copying from the azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to do it using Rest Apis. We can use any of the below Azure Rest Apis to get the primary key and create the Connection String out of it:
1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/iothubresource/listkeys
Get the keyDetails from the json object which has "keyName" as "iothubowner"
and build the connectionString using the format:
"HostName={your-IoTHub-name}.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey={PrimaryKey-value}"

2.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/iothubresource/getkeysforkeyname
Pass the keyName as "iothubowner" in the url and get the required keyDetails to create the connection String as mentioned above.